# What do angle brackets ($\langle\rangle$ ) mean in mathematics/statistics (autocorrelations)?

Tags: statistics, notation, correlation

Okay, so the logarithmic return on a stock is given by:

$$r_τ (t) = \ln P(t+τ) - \ln P(t),$$ where τ is the interval of time.

I have no problem calculating that. My question comes to the following formula:

$$ρ(T) \sim 〈r_τ (t+T) \cdot r_τ (t)〉$$

This is supposedly the autocorrelation function of log-returns. What's the deal with the brackets?

Comment: Not too sure about stocks, but the angular brackets commonly indicate expected value in statistics. Would that make sense in this context?

Comment: In physics, it's suppose to be an inner product. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134156/what-does-langle-y-lm-y-lambda-mu-rangle-delta-l-lambda-delta http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173407/a-notation-question-langle-x-y-rangle

Comment: The angle brackets probably represent a time-average.

Answer (score 3):

In [Bra-ket notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation), we denote an inner product of two vectors $|u\rangle,\,|v\rangle$ as $\langle u|v\rangle$, where the map from vectors $|v\rangle$ in the inner product space to scalars $\langle u|v\rangle$ is a linear map labelled $\langle u|$. (The set of such linear maps is a vector space called the dual space; its elements are bras $\langle u|$, whereas the original space has ket elements $|v\rangle$.)

If the matrix $M$ keeps $|v\rangle$ in the same vector space by mapping it to $M|v\rangle$, $\langle u|M|v\rangle$ is not only an inner product; if $|u\rangle,\,|v\rangle$ are elements of some basis, this inner product is a matrix element in that basis.

In quantum mechanics, to each observable $O$ there corresponds an $\widehat{O}$ such that in the pure state $|\psi\rangle$ the expectation of $O$ is $\langle\psi|\widehat{O}|\psi\rangle$. If the state can be taken for granted, we abbreviate this as $\langle\widehat{O}\rangle$.

Even with classical probability, we can express the covariance of two random variables as an inner product on a vector space: namely, a quotient space of equivalence classes of finite-variance random variables. I go through the details [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3071367/whats-so-special-about-standard-deviation/3071375#3071375). Then $A,\,B$ has covariance $\langle AB\rangle-\langle A\rangle\langle B\rangle$, but the second term can be deleted if at least one of $A,\,B$ has mean $0$.

If variables have variance $1$, their covariance is also their correlation. [Autocorrelation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation) is one special case.

Answer (score -2):

A clear and concise definition I found in [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AngleBracket.html) which states a below,
[image: Angle Bracket]

Its history is discussed by Professor Brailsford in Computerphile youtube channel [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1IdlBFaifcs).

Another question was asked [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/387078/56208) which is more in the context of statistics and can be helpful to understand.